# fieldset does to follow its parent's height in Internet Exp

Tags: css

Please check the link in IE

http://jsfiddle.net/HtAJw/

I am trying to get the fieldset to take parent's height. in Chrome in works fine but IE mess it up.
IS there any way to make it work on IE?

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed height for the parent, then set the children with `height: 100%` (meaning 100% of the parent element).

Comment: do u mean in .child class I should set the Height? I cant do that coz I want .child div to adjust the height with parent and parent height increases with its content.

Comment: I mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/XEQbS/. You give `.parent` a height in pixels, and `height: 100%` to `.child`.

Comment: I do not want to set any height to the parent coz I want it grow with its content and field set to follow it's parent's height. the link u provided does not have height set either

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to save that fiddle. I really can't get it to work in IE, maybe you'll have to rethink the whole thing, or look for a js solution.